# Generating code from an existing database EF7

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to `generate code` from my `database` but i get `errors` : `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred`. ---> Method not found

this is my project.json:

```
{
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"version": "1.0.0-*",

"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8-15797",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8-15797",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-beta8-15797",
    "Remotion.Linq": "2.0.0-rc-001"
},

"commands": {
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
  "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},

"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
},

"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
],
"publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
]
}
```

How do i Generating code from an existing database EF7

I'm using this command :

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "ConnectionString" EntityFramework.SqlServer
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade all packages to be consistent. You have beta5 and beta 8 mixed. If you still experience errors, please check or file and issue to the appropriate repository. https://github.com/aspnet